# How do I find previous and next key/value in a map?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, vector, stdmap

I have a map which has the following data:

```
id    prev abundance  thing
1573  -1      0       book
1864  1573    39      beds
2075  1864    41      tray
1760  2075    46      cups
```

The map is:

```
map<int id, Abund*> oldMap;
struct Abund
{
int prev;
int abundance;
string thing;
}
```

I need to now create a new map which should look like this:

```
 id2    prev2 prevAbun next2  nextAbun  thing2
 1573     -1            1864   39        book
 1864   1573     0      2075   41        beds
 2075   1864     39     1760   46        tray
 1760   2075     41                      cups
```

The previous and the next row from map 1 should become the columns in newMap
So far I've created a new map and new struct:

```
struct NewAbund
{
vector<int> prev2;
vector<int> prevAbun;
vector<int> next2;
vector<int> nextAbun;
string thing2;
}
map<int id2, NewAbund*> newMap;
```

Now I have no idea how should the logic work for getting the previous row from oldMap and putting it as value in newMap. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just iterate through the map, you'll get iterators which point to pair in order by key. So if you remember the previous iterator during the iteration, you'll have two consecutive iterators, from which you can fill in your new vectors.

On the other hand, since you can always find the next and previous key in an ordered map (although it does take O(log n) time), it may not really be necessary to go to all the trouble to denormalize the data. If you're using c++11, you'll find std::next and std::prev which will make it really easy to perform these operations. (If not -- why not? -- you can easily define them in terms of std::advance.)

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of std::next and std::prev but when I use it, I get this error: 'No member named next in namespace std'

Comment: You need to (a) make sure you're using c++11 (for gcc, it's --std=c++11 or --std=c++0x, depending on gcc version), and (b) #include <iterator>